# Sending a fax via a mobile connected via a USB cable

Tags: 13.10, fax

I have a smartphone which I can connect through a USB (Universal Serial Bus) cable. I wish to send a fax to a given number. Which software in Ubuntu can I use to send the fax?

Answer (score 1):

Most mobile technologies cannot support faxing. The quality of the connection is not good enough to properly transmit fax tones. However, you may consider setting up an account with an online fax provider if you wish to fax from your computer.